# How to access the data of a row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, row

I have the following table which forms the header of the page:

```
<table class="wpHeaderTable">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:10%;"></td>
        <td style="width:10%;"></td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;">data1</td>
        <td style="width:auto;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;">
            <a href="<s:url action=" ViewAppeals "/>" onclick="check" style="color:#FFFFF;text-decoration:none;">View Appeals</a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;">data3</td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;">data4</td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;">data5</td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;">data6</td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;">data7</td>
        <td style="width:10%;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When that page is loaded, the `ViewAppeals` data of this table should have a background color of yellow and others should have background color of blue.

The `ViewAppeals` data is a link which when clicked will redirect to another page.

How can I do this?

I have tried this script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').click(function(){
        $('tr td').css({ 'color' : 'none'});
        $('td', this).css({ 'color' : '#CCC' });
      }); 
});
```

Comment: define a id of table, using Jquery you can change color.

Comment: You are not using ajax to load content for each page as "Clicking on this link it will redirect to another page" is suggesting. So, you should have a .wpHeaderTable on each page. So why not just set background-color of currently selected td for each page?

Comment: After defining the id,say id="table1", how to change the color...Could you please help me with some code?

Comment: @roasted : actually I am not having .wpHeaderTable in each page...I am having a page called Header.jsp where I have this table and I include this jsp in every pages...

Comment: @mukund: Can you please post [**any code you have tried so far**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) in addition if you have a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) replicating your current issue we can look at it and sort it out. But if you have no issue and only want someone to do the work for you then you may or may not get a solution provided. If you don;t know where to start have a look at [**jQuery selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) To target a table something like `$("table th tr").eq(1)` would for example give you the second `tr` element wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: @wahl : I have added the code which I tried...

Comment: Jeez, three "." is not a substitute for a carriage return!

Comment: @liam : I dont understand what you are telling

Comment: Break your explanations up, writing one huge block of text is not easily read. Putting "..." instead of breaking it up just makes it worse.

Comment: @laim : I did not write any huge block of text...Just 4-5 lines...

Answer (score 0):

First, assign an `id` attribute to the `<tr>`

```
<tr id="someid">

</div>
```

Then select the child `<td>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr#someid').click(function(){
        $("tr td").css({ 'color' : 'none'});
        $(this + " > td").css({ 'color' : '#CCC' });
      }); 
});
```

You can use the `>` selector to select the child of the clicked element (in this case the `<tr>`)